# Catch blank (including all-whitespace) form submissions

Tags: php, post

If have a problem on my site that users can post empty messages if they use space.

#### Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // check for empty fields
  if (empty($_POST['headline']) || empty($_POST['text']) ||
      empty($_POST['forum_id'])) {
      header("Refresh: 2; url=/add-thread"); 
      die('You must fill out every field.');
  }

// No errors? Save.
else {
$headline = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO threads (headline, text, date, forum_id, user_id)
             VALUES ('$headline', '$text', NOW(), '$_POST[forum_id]', '$user[id]')");

header("Location: /thread/".mysql_insert_id()."");
}

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should also escape the $_POST['forum_id']. Users can still manipulate it.

Comment: You don’t need that empty string after `mysql_insert_id()`. It’s funny how often that is made. Oh, and use absolute URIs in the Location header field.

Answer (score 9):

`trim()` the text inputs. You can do that easily like this:

```
// get input vars and trim space
$callback = array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => 'trim');
$fields = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
    'headline' => $callback,
    'text'     => $callback,
    'forum_id' => $callback,
));

// check for empty fields by counting how many are set
if ( count($fields) != count(array_filter($fields)) ) {
    // something was unset
}
```

Comment: gives me Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\WAMP\www\add-thread.php on line 13

Comment: You can't use a function call inside empty(). Do it separately, then check the input length is > 0.

Comment: A quick way to apply trim to all post elements: $_POST = array_map( 'trim', $_POST ).

Answer (score 3):

The empty function checks for variables that meet a set criteria, from [the manual](http://us.php.net/empty)

> Returns FALSE if var  has a non-empty and non-zero value.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Your $_POST fields actually contain something like this

```
"   ";
```

This isn't and empty string, but a string that's filled with whitespace characters.

Before using empty(), trim() the white-space from your POSTed values

```
$trimmed_post = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $trimmed_post[$key] = $value;
}
if(!empty($trimmed_post['headline'])){
    //...
}
```

You don't need to put the new values into a new array, but I'm not a big fan of changing what's in the auto-generated superglobals.

One final note, you can't do something like this

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['headline']))){
   //...
}
```

because the empty function expects to be passed an actual variable.  You could do something like this instead

```
if('' != trim($_POST['headline'])){
//...
}
```

This is probably the best approach to take.  You reduce the number of functions that you need to call, users can post entries with a value of 0, and the code is more explicit about what it does.  Another form you'll see is

```
if(trim($_POST['headline'])){

}
```

This works because PHP evaluates an empty string ('') as false, and a non empty string as true.  I tend to avoid this form because I've found a lot of PHP bugs crop up around misunderstandings on how the equality operators get boolean values out of certain types.  Being explicit helps reduce occurrences of these types of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note: You're injecting the value of `$_POST['forum_id']` into the SQL; that's not a good idea, since a user could manipulate that value as desired, even if it is coming from a hidden field. It would be wise to escape the value, or at least pass it through [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/intval) and ensure it's an integer (assuming integral post identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that trimming is the way to go.  Here's a much easier way to go about it:

```
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!empty($_POST['headline']) && !empty($_POST['text']) &&
!empty($_POST['forum_id']))
```

For the logic.

You'd have to switch it around though.

UPDATE to clarify:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['headline']) && 
!empty($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['forum_id'])) {

    $headline = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO threads (headline, text, date, forum_id, user_id)
         VALUES ('$headline', '$text', NOW(), '$_POST[forum_id]', '$user[id]')");

    header("Location: /thread/".mysql_insert_id()."");
}
else
{
  header("Refresh: 2; url=/add-thread"); 
  die('You must fill out every field.');    
}
```

}

Comment: You have to switch the logic around.

Comment: empty() doesn't return true for strings consisting of whitespace, which is what the questioner is attempting to deal with.

Comment: I can post "<br />" or " " or "­" or "<p>&nbsp</p>" or any combinations of these and still pass a trim and empty checks. So its pretty futile.

Answer (score -1):

Right after checking for a submission:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => &$value ) $value = trim($value);
```

**edit in response to asker's comment:**

Odd that it didn't work as above.  Here was my exercise to confirm it would.

```
tbramble@wayfarer:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $arr = array('one',' two', ' three ');
php > print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] =>  two
    [2] =>  three 
)
php > foreach ( $arr as $key => &$value ) $value = trim($value);
php > print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

Must have something to do with working on a superglobal instead of a normal array.

Comment: that didnt work but this did: foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = trim($value);

Comment: also - entries in $_GET and $_POST can be arrays so u have to go thru recurssively

Comment: Good call, Arin.  Definitely not a drop-in solution for any occasion.

Answer (score -1):

I trim every `$_GET` & `$_POST` variable as soon as the app starts. try something like this:

```
function trimArray(&$array) {
    if (empty($array)) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (! is_array($v)) {
            $array[$k] = trim($v);
        } else {
            trimArray($v);
        }
    }
}

if (! empty($_GET)) {
    trimArray($_GET);
}
if (! empty($_POST)) {
    trimArray($_POST);
}
```